# odoo: printing qweb report using wizard

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

i have two reports cout_materiel_facture_detail_report.xml (detailed report) and cout_materiel_facture_report.xml (simple report) and have a wizard where the user inputs some data and chooses whether he/she wants to print the simple report or the detailed one. Here is the wizard's class:

```
class CoutMaterielFactureWizard(models.TransientModel):
_name = 'gc.cout_materiel_facture_wizard'

directeur_parc_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string='Directeur Parc')

procedure = fields.Char(string='Procedure')
version = fields.Char(string='Verion')
date_realisation = fields.Date(string='Date realisation')

# is_landscape = fields.Boolean(string='Mode paysage?')
is_detail = fields.Boolean(string='Version simplifiee?')

@api.multi
def do_toggle_print(self):
    cout_materiel = self.env['gc.cout_materiel'].browse(self._context.get('active_id', False))
    cout_materiel.write({
        'directeur_parc_id': self.directeur_parc_id.id
    })
    # Print the simple report
    if not self.is_detail:

        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
            'name': 'gestion_cout.cout_materiel_facture_report_template',
            'report_name': 'gestion_cout.cout_materiel_facture_report_template',
        }
    # Print the detailed report
    else:
        sql = "SELECT  SUM(h_sup)+SUM(h_exp),SUM(h_im),count(*),SUM(total), famille FROM gc_cout_materiel_line where " \
              "cout_materiel_id =%s group by famille "
        self.env.cr.execute(sql, (cout_materiel.id,))
        results = self.env.cr.fetchall()
        if len(results) > 0:
            line_ids = []
            for nbht, nbhim, qte, prix_total, famille in results:
                line_ids.append((0, 0, {
                    'famille': famille,
                    'type': 'VA',
                    'qte': qte,
                    'nbr_heures': nbht,
                    'nbr_heures_im': nbhim,
                    'nbr_jours': 28,
                    'prix_unitaire': 'VA',
                    'prix_total': prix_total,
                        }))
            self.env['gc.cout_materiel_facture_temp'].create({
                'chantier_name': cout_materiel.chantier_id.name,
                'mois_name': cout_materiel.mois_id.name,
                'num_annexe': cout_materiel.num_annexe,
                'expediteur': cout_materiel.expediteur,
                'destinateur': cout_materiel.destinateur,
                'application_date': cout_materiel.application_date,
                'date_realisation': self.date_realisation,
                'directeur_parc_name': self.directeur_parc_id.name,
                'procedure': self.procedure,
                'version': self.version,
                'prix_total_global': cout_materiel.total_global,
                'line_ids': line_ids,
            })
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
            'name': 'gestion_cout.gc_cout_materiel_facture_detail_report_template',
            'report_name': 'gestion_cout.gc_cout_materiel_facture_detail_report_template',
        }
```

[But i get this error after i hit the print button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAkeK.png)

I checked out the database and found both reports are present there.

Any help? please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i managed to solve my problem!!
Here is what i did:

- I created a method in the wizard model which returns a list of objects that i whant to print and linked the wizard to the qweb report.
- Then i called the method from the qweb report using object.my_mehtod() in a t-foreach loop, where **object** represents the wizard.

---

With this way i am able to create complex reports and print them easily. One can use this method to get data from several tables and organize the data and retur them as a list.

I hope that it will help someone.

Best regards!!